# Human fight indestructible bell-shaped aliens called "bellers"

Tags: story-identification

The central theme as I remember it is a battle between humans and the "Bellers".  The Bellers are a people/aliens who always have a bell shaped device around them within close proximity, because should there current body die, they can transfer there consciousness out of a body and into another body.  The bells have limited movement, and can fit onto a humans head, where probes can be used to extract or implant the essence of a mind into a body.  The bells are all but indestructible, and can essentially prolong ones life indefinitely.  I can't remember if it is a short story or a book.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   We don't know when you were a kid, so approximately what year was this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[*A Private Cosmos*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11920), a novel by [Philip José Farmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Jos%C3%A9_Farmer), the third book in his [*World of Tiers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?769) series; maybe you will recognize one of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?11920). It can be borrowed (for free but registration required) from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/privatecosmos0000phil_z8s7/page/52/mode/2up).

From [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Tiers):

> The third book chronicles Kickaha's adventures while the events of the second book are occurring. He meets three dispossessed Lords (one of whom is Anana) who are fleeing an army led by the Black Bellers – artificial intelligences capable of taking over the bodies of human hosts.

Excerpt:

> "Anyway, the psyche is the other half of the 'real' person. And when the duplicate soma-brain is built up in the Beller, the psyche, or soul, transfers to the Beller. And when the Beller retransfers the mental contents to the new host, the psyche then goes to the new host."

Answer (score 11):

Could this be *[Behind the Walls of Terra](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1875528.Behind_the_Walls_of_Terra)* (1970) by Philip José Farmer?

> Recently, Wolff and C'hryseis had mysteriously disappeared, probably
> because of the machinations of some Lord of another universe. Kiekaha
> had run into Anana, who, with two other Lords, was fleeing from the
> Black Bellers. The Bcllers had originally been devices created in the
> biolabs of the Lords and intended for housing of the minds of the Lords
> during mind transference from one body to another. But the bell-shaped
> and indestructible machines had developed into entities with their own intelligence. These had succeeded in transferring their minds into
> the bodies of Lords and then began to wage a secret war on the Lords.
> They were found out. and a long and savage struggle began, with all
> the Bellers supposedly captured and imprisoned in a specially made
> universe. However, fifty-one had been overlooked, and these, after ten
> thousand years of dormancy, had gotten into human bodies again and
> were once more loose.
>
> [image]

This book was part of his [*World of Tiers*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/57350-world-of-tiers) series of novels, but seems the most likely choice based on your description.